# String split column and join to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have 2 tables like this :

**Job Offers:**

```
+----+------------+------------+
| ID |    Name    | Categories |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 | Programmer | 1,2        |
|  2 | Analyst    | 3          |
+----+------------+------------+
```

**Categories:**

```
+----+-----------------+
| ID |      Name       |
+----+-----------------+
|  1 | Programming     |
|  2 | Web Programming |
|  3 | Analysis        |
+----+-----------------+
```

We've got a string split that takes a string, a delimiter and returns a table, my problem is I'm really not sure how to integrate the table in my query to join the job offers and the categories.

My thinking is that it would be something like this :

```
SELECT
    O.[ID]                  AS OfferID,
    O.[Name]                AS OfferName,
    CAT.[CategoryName]      AS CategoryName,
    CAT.[CategoryID]        AS CategoryID
FROM
    JobOffers AS O
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT 
        O.[ID]              AS OfferID,
        C.[CategoryID]      AS CategoryID,
        C.[Name]            AS Name
    FROM
        (
            SELECT *
            FROM [dbo].[Split](O.[Categories], ',')
        ) AS CJ
    LEFT JOIN
        [Categories] AS C
        ON C.CategoryID = CJ.items  
) AS CAT ON CAT.OfferID = O.[ID]
```

Currently I have two errors saying:

- `multi-part identifier O.[ID] cannot be bound`
- `multi-part identifier O.[Categories] cannot be bound`
- `incorrect syntax near AS` (last line)

So clearly the problem is how I construct my subquery.

Comment: user defined functions like this on larger data sets will give you poor performance. consider creating a new table JobOfferCategories (JobOfferId, CategoryId) instead of the categories column

Comment: Unfortunately I'm limited on technical side as the database is legacy and they don't plan on changing it anytime soon. Currently they do a fetch on joboffers and all categories and parse it C# side. Trying to optimise things a bit and include fulltext on DB side so the result of this select will basically be a view.

Comment: Side note: starting in SS 2016, there is a built in function called [`STRING_SPLIT`](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql-server/4113/string-functions/15779/string-split#t=201610122033488805938)

Comment: can anyone help on how to achieve this in sql server 2012 since there is not STRING_SPLIT function

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can greatly simplify this to something like this.

```
SELECT
    O.[ID]                  AS OfferID,
    O.[Name]                AS OfferName,
    c.[CategoryName]      AS CategoryName,
    c.[CategoryID]        AS CategoryID
FROM
    JobOffers AS O
outer apply [dbo].[Split](O.[Categories], ',') s
left join Categories as C on c.CategoryID = s.Items
```

The concern I have is your splitter. If there is more than a single select statement the performance is going to suffer horribly. For a good explanation of various splitters available you can visit this article.

http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: Good link. Also note that starting in SS 2016, there is a built in function called [`STRING_SPLIT`](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql-server/4113/string-functions/15779/string-split#t=201610122033488805938)

Comment: i cant see this SPLIT function in sql server 2012

Comment: @AmeerPappay that SPLIT function is a user defined function. You would want to read the article I linked at the end. The native STRING_SPLIT function is not available until sql server 2016 or later.

Answer (score 20):

From SQL SERVER 2016 we can use sql inbuilt function STRING_SPLIT
as below :

```
SELECT * FROM JobOffers as j 
outer apply STRING_SPLIT(j.[Categories], ',') s
left join dbo.Categories as c on c.CategoryID =s.value
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can live with one row per category then this will work:

```
select jo.*, c.name as category
from joboffers jo join
     categories c
     on ',' + jo.categories + ',' like '%,' + cast(c.id) + ',%';
```

Re-aggregating them into a string is painful in SQL Server (but very possible).

Note:  you have a really, really bad data structure.  So you should fix it as mentioned in a comment.  Why is it bad?

- You are storing numbers as strings.
- You have ids that don't have a foreign key relationship to the reference table.
- You are storing multiple values in a single field.